# Do the logarithmic corrections to black hole entropy imply corrections to their energy or temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, black-holes, temperature, entropy

Could somebody help guide the thinking in this situation?

Do the corrections to entropy $S$, like those of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111001, affect the temperature of a black hole, or its mass, or both, or neither?

The Schwarzschild black hole entropy $S_{BH}$ with logarithmic corrections is given by 
$$
 S_{BH} = S_0 + (3/2) \ln S_0
$$
where $S_0= (c^3 A) / (4G\hbar )$ is the Bekenstein Hawking entropy, and $A$ the area of the black hole.

So the question is: is there also a logarithmic correction to mass (energy) or to temperature of the black hole? Why or why not?

The entropy of a black hole is thus not given exactly by "one quarter of the area". There are logarithmic corrections to that statement. The question is:

(1) Is the mass of a black hole *exactly* "proportional to its radius", or are there logarithmic corrections to this statement?

(2) Is the temperature of a black hole *exactly* "inversely proportional to its radius"  or are there logarithmic corrections to this statement?

Comment: Please be specific about “the logarithmic corrections” that you are referring to, such as with a link to a paper.

Comment: Rather than just adding the link, could you copy the relevant passage and highlight what it is that you are questioning (be specific about what you fathom versus what you don’t)

Comment: I did as you asked.

Comment: I extended the question to make it even clearer.

Comment: related : [How is the logarithmic correction to the entropy of a non extremal black hole derived?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27955/how-is-the-logarithmic-correction-to-the-entropy-of-a-non-extremal-black-hole-de?rq=1) even if I did not consider in my answer the orgin of the log-correction from a Cardy-like perspective.

Comment: The "imply" bothers me in the title. Apart from the "affect" at the beginning, the details of the question appears to be a better starting point: there are log-corrections to the entropy, are there also log-corrections for other thermodynamical quantities, resulting from the same physical process?

Comment: also, the title is not as precise as the details concerning the necessity for the corrections to the energy/temperature to be logarithmic (instead of some other quantum corrections).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the answer is that only entropy has logarithmic corrections. Neither energy nor temperature has such corrections. The logarithmic corrections of entropy are due to statistical fluctuations. These fluctuations have no effect on temperature or mass/energy.

Comment: so, aren't quantum fluctuations that lead to an effective black hole temperature through Bogoliubov transformations? Perhaps it is unexpected that fluctuations have no effect on temperature. What effects are in play to result in the absence of an influence?

Comment: Can you edit the first question and make it clearer? I do not understand the grammar of it.

Comment: I downvoted the answer. I will be happy to undo whenever:
- some background and definitions will be given (what are those statistical fluctuations, and why only consider these? I know about other sources of log corrections, see my link in the comment above)
- the affirmation (no effect on E & T) will be clearly justified (It is unclear for E in the paper you cited, and T isn't and can't be AFAIK studied that way)